# Get Latitude and Longitude of all location that are within 10km radius of my current location through google map(using PHP)

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am new to Google map things. i have a table in which there are list of all the location( the location of super stores) with their Latitude and Longitude .

Now i want to know all possible location(may b Latitude and Longitude ) of these super stores that are within 10km radius of my current location.

I have no idea how i can do this using Google map (in php code).
What Google map API should i used ?
Any suggestion ,project code, information will be helpful for me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Some code samples? What have you tried?

Comment: @tntu thanks for your reply ..actually i have no idea where to begin means what should i used . i have tried nothing

Comment: At least provide more info on how your system needs to work. In PHP cau cannot interact with the maps api unless you use some javascript code to pass data to php.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [Radius search with Google Maps and MySQL](http://spinczyk.net/blog/2009/10/04/radius-search-with-google-maps-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 10):

You can Use Following Query of Mysql to get all stores within specified miles

```
select * from stores where lat!='' and lng!='' and ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $centerpoints['lat'] . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $centerpoints['lng'] . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $centerpoints['lat'] . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < " . $distanceInMile
```

Comment: How do you calculate $centerpoints['lng'] and $centerpoints['lat']?

Comment: What is 3959 in the query actually does ?

Answer (score 7):

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
Have a look at above. Should give you a good idea.

> To find locations in your markers table that are within a certain
>   radius distance of a given latitude/longitude, you can use a SELECT
>   statement based on the Haversine formula. The Haversine formula is
>   used generally for computing great-circle distances between two pairs
>   of coordinates on a sphere. An in-depth mathemetical explanation is
>   given by Wikipedia and a good discussion of the formula as it relates
>   to programming is on Movable Type's site.
>
> Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that
>   are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It
>   calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row
>   and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where
>   the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by
>   distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead
>   of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

Comment: Where is that SQL statement?

Comment: Check under "Finding Locations with MySQL" topic

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLatLong(lat, lng, radius) {
  const earth = 6371 // earth radius in miles
  const maxLat = ((lat + Math.PI / 2) * 180) / Math.PI
  const minLat = ((lat - Math.PI / 2) * 180) / Math.PI
  const maxLng = ((lng + (Math.PI * radius) / earth) * 180) / Math.PI
  const minLng = ((lng - (Math.PI * radius) / earth) * 180) / Math.PI
  return {
    maxLat: maxLat,
    minLat: minLat,
    maxLng: maxLng,
    minLng: minLng,
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be PHP or make use of the Google Map APIs.

Comment: This is incorrect, as your max/minLat isn't using the radius variable, hence is simply adding an arbitrary distance (which is very large as i tested it).