# Mark multi location in database and compare distance them using GoogleMap?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, ionic-framework, android-gps

I have hybrid app (Ionic 1) and contains some locations in my database , i want to check some locations near this my positons now ( GPS ) radius < 10km .help me solution to solve it ? using Google Map ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in your back-end or server side by passing your current position details like lat and lang.[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)  for a guideline how to do that.In this they used PHP as a back-end technology so you need to try in your technology.[check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949476/get-latitude-and-longitude-of-all-location-that-are-within-10km-radius-of-my-cur)